# size variation in memory layout of c programming

Tags: c, debugging, memory-management

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int i;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

My Output from Command Prompt:

```
PS E:\Programs\C\Programmieren in C> size file_16.exe
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   2957    1928     480    5365    14f5 file_16.exe
PS E:\Programs\C\Programmieren in C> gcc file_16.c -o file_16.exe
PS E:\Programs\C\Programmieren in C> size file_16.exe
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   2957    1928     448    5333    14d5 file_16.exe
```

Considering my c code, I am trying to visualize the variable size allocation in the data and bss layer. I can't seem to understand what is exactly happening there. First I define and declare `static int i;` and then visualize the size of bss layer in the cmd. Then I initialize it to some value, let's say 24, and run it again. The size of the bss layer decreases by 32 instead of 4 bytes. But there is no change in the data layer as I was expecting a change.

PS: I am running this code in Code Blocks and using GCC.

Would be helpful if someone could explain what is happening here ad why?

Comment: Please do not post your code and output as images.

Comment: How can I then attach it?

Comment: By copy-pasting the text into your question.

Comment: Indent text by 4 spaces so that it will be formatted as code. Otherwise just leave empty lines above and below the output: we'll figure it out :)

Comment: You might want to create assembler from your code and see exactly what goes where ... `gcc -S file16.c` and then examine the `file16.s` file created

Comment: how do I examine the file_16.s file? Can you also please share the cmd?

Comment: `> type file16.s` (`$ cat file16.s` in Un\*x) or maybe you prefer `> notepad file16.s` (`$ vim file16.s` or `$ emacs file16.s` or ... in Un\*x) or find a way to open it within your IDE

Comment: Thank you. I will try it and if I have any more ques, will write back.

Comment: Not even `gcc -O0` seems to actually allocate the variable. Make it `volatile` and access it in main(), if you want a guarantee that it 1) gets at all allocated and 2) ends up in .bss RAM.

Comment: @Lundin making the variable externally linkable (removing the `static` storage class) should also work, unless the compiler is doing link-level optimization.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yeah, that should work too on most compilers.

Comment: @Lundin and unless you place variables in separate segments which is very common. It will be then discarded if not used.

Comment: It is very likely that linker is using 32 bytes alignment and you already have something (from the startup code or glibc in the .data segment. It does not have to be increased but .bss has to.

Comment: @wdl4076 – The option `-Wl,-Map,file_16.map` generates a map file where you can look for the variable in question. At the end of the containing section you'll probably see an ALIGN directive.